# Proving $A \in B \land B \subseteq C \to A \in C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

We are given $A \in B \land B \subseteq C \to A \in C$, 
how to proove that it is true for any $A,B,C$?

I am having trouble proving it correctly...
This is what i am thinking:

- $A \in B$ means $B\{ A$, other elements from $B\}$
- $B \subseteq C$ means $C\{ A$, other elements from $B$, other elements from $C\}$
- $A$ belongs to $C$, so it is true.

Is this correct? and how to write every elements excluding $x$?

Comment: It is okay but it would be better if you could make it more formal. Here are some ideas: if $a \in B$ and $B \subseteq C$, you can use the definition of $B \subseteq C$ to conclude that $a \in C$. What's the definition of $B \subseteq C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt at proving it is not clear to me, so I will not comment much on its accuracy. It seems like you have a rough understanding of the underlying notions though.

---

Suppose $A\in B$ and $B\subseteq C$. By definition of $B\subseteq C$, for all $b\in B$, we have $b\in C$. Let $b=A$. Thus $A\in C$.

Answer (score 2):

In set-theory $\in$ is a primitive notion that has no definition.

It is just some kind of relation that two sets have or have not: $$B\in C\text{ or }B\notin C$$

Based on $\in$ a new relation $\subseteq$ is *defined* by stating that: $$B\subseteq C\iff x\in C\text{ for every }x\text{ that satisfies: }x\in B $$

So - by definition - if $B\subseteq C$ then $A\in C$ is a true statement whenever $A\in B$.

This comes to the same as saying that: $$A\in B\wedge B\subseteq C\implies A\in C$$is a true statement.

So here a proof is actually nothing more than the application of a definition.

Comment: I didn't know $\in$ was primitive. As such, this comment might not be helpful, but the naïve view of $\in$ is that it says the set on its left side is "*inside*" the set on its right; maybe that's worth editing into your answer (and I'll leave that up to you). Although of heard of, say, geometry being taught *without any diagrams or talk of shapes*, it is nonetheless instructive to "know" what lines & points are, at least by example, even though they, too, are primitive.

Comment: @Shaun I think that your comment on its own is enough on this matter, so will not add something. Actually it is only a shift/translation from $\in$ to the primitive notion "inside" (what is that in mathematics?) and gives at most a way to visualize (very useful indeed). Somewhere definitions must stop. You could say that the relation $a\text{ defined by means of }b$ is well founded, i.e. every non-empty subset has a least (i.e. primitive) element.