# If $A, B, C$ are three sets with $A \subseteq B$ and $B \in C$, does it follow that $A \subseteq C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818825/a-b-and-c-are-sets-if-a-subseteq-b-and-b-in-c-then-a-not-subset) question, and by playing around with examples, it is clear to me that we can construct sets $A, B, C$ such that  $A \subseteq B$ and $B \in C$ and $A \subseteq C$. But is this always the case?

I think not (but I want to be sure).

Let $A = \{1\}, B = \{1, 2\},$ and $C = \{\{1,2\}\}$.

Then $A \subseteq B, B \in C$ but $A \not\subseteq C$.

Is this correct? And so, does this combined with the linked answer mean that in general, if $A \subseteq B, B \in C$ then we cannot make any general claim about $A$'s relationship with $C$?

Comment: [This might cause confusion but this question is related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3057660/104041)

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct. You can always put $C= \{B\}$ and if $A\ne B$, then $A\notin C$.